# Python Pandas - Removing trailing numbers and the remaining words in string

Tags: python, string, pandas

How do I remove numbers and everything behind the number using pandas? Basically anything with a number as a separate word and remove anything behind the separate word.

For example:

```
ABC,2 QUEEN = ABC

ABC 3 QUEEN = ABC

ABC PTE LTD YES123 = ABC PTE LTD YES123

ABC PTE LTD YES 123 = ABC PTE LTD
```

Comment: why isn't `yes123` removed?

Comment: it should not be removed as it does not start with a number

Comment: okay, can you try the code in my answer and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['MyCol'].replace('[\,\s]+\d+.+', '')
```

Comment: df['MyCol'].str.replace('[\,\s]+\d+.+', '') would work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think pandas is the best way to accomplish that task, you could use ntlk tokenization to separate your row by each word in it, and then iterate through tokenized words, keep those words in a separate array until a number is encountered, in which case you can use 'break' statement and move to next row

Answer (score 0):

This is quite crude but please try

```
df['MyCol'].str.split('[ |,][0-9]+')
```

The drawback is that you will have to extract index 0 of the returned list to overwrite the original column. Alternatively, set the parameter *Expand=True* and drop all the successive columns that are generated.

```
df['MyCol'].str.split('[ |,][0-9]+', expand=True)
```

**Output:**

```
0           [ABC,  QUEEN]

1           [ABC,  QUEEN]

2    [ABC PTE LTD YES123]

3     [ABC PTE LTD YES, ]
```

Comment: I believe YES123 in the third row is intended to be kept as it's part of the string

Comment: YES123 is intended to be part of the string.. and Output 0 and 1 should result in ABC without the QUEEN..

Comment: Yeah, you can just drop Index1 since Index0 is basically what you need. That said, I think Ashish's answer should work if you use df.str.replace instead of df.replace.